# how can use $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{e^x - e^{\sin \left( x \right)} }}{{x - \sin \left( x \right)}}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can calcul
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{e^x  - e^{\sin \left( x \right)} }}{{x - \sin \left( x \right)}}$$

Comment: `expr = (Exp[x] - Exp[Sin[x]])/(x - Sin[x]);
Limit[expr, x -> 0]` gives 1

Comment: This looks like it should be moved to the *Mathematics* stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

> but why

For the why part, you need little bit of math. You can always start by looking at series expansion of all terms

```
expr = (Exp[x] - Exp[Sin[x]])/(x - Sin[x]);
Limit[expr, x -> 0]
 (*1*)
```

Now expand all in taylor (used 4 terms to make it easy to see)

```
expr = (Normal@Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 4}] - 
  Normal@Series[Exp[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 4}])/(x - Normal@Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4}])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Simplify[%]
(* 1 + x *)
```

So clearly when `x->0` then `1+x` will go to `1`.

There are other ways to do this by hand of course.

**by hand**

$$\frac{e^x-e^{sin(x)}}{x-sin(x)}=e^x\frac{1-e^{sin(x)-x}}{x-sin(x)} $$

$$1-e^{sin(x)-x}\sim -(sin(x)-x) $$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{x->0}\frac{e^x-e^{sin(x)}}{x-sin(x)}=\lim_{x->0}e^x\frac{x-sin(x)}{x-sin(x)}=1$$